# Must IRET  be used when returning from an interrupt?

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system, linux-kernel, x86

IRET can restore the registers from the stack,including EFLAGS, ESP, EIP and so on, but we can also restore the registers all by ourselves.  For example, "movl" can be used to restore the %esp register, "jmp" can jump the address pointed to EIP which is stored on the stack.

The linux kernel returns from all interrupts by IRET, which is a weight instruction.

Some kernel operations (like context switches) happen frequently.

Isn't IRET a waste?

Comment: What do you mean a "weight instruction" ?

Comment: the instruction does a lot of work, and cost much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides all the heavy stuff `IRET` can and often should do in addition to a mere blend of `POPF+RETF`, there's one more thing that it does. It has a special function related to *non-maskable interrupts* (`NMIs`).

Concurrent NMIs are delivered to the CPU one by one. `IRET` signals to the NMI circuitry that another NMI can now be delivered. No other instruction can do this signalling.
If NMIs could preempt execution of other NMI ISRs, they would be able to cause a stack overflow, which rarely is a good thing. Unless we're talking about this wonderful website. :)

So, all in all, `IRET` is not a waste.

Comment: Does it mean only IRET can be used when returning from an interrupt?

Comment: In some situations it's the only choice. NMIs is one of them. If you use interrupt/exception tasks, that's another. Double fault handlers must be tasks. Besides, IRET is very useful for transferring control to less privileged code (to execute user-mode callbacks for example). If it's there, why not use it?

Comment: :" When an interrupt is sent by the PIC, the PIC will not send another interrupt from that same source until it gets acknowledged through an I/O port." Who tells the current interrupt handler has been finished,IRET or something else?

Comment: The ISR sends an `EOI` (=End Of Interrupt) command to the PIC, then does IRET. Have more questions? Make them questions, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because doing all that manually would need even more CPU clocks.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedija](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Advanced_Interrupts):

> The actual code that is invoked when an interrupt occurs is called the
>   Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). When an exception occurs, a program
>   invokes an interrupt, or the hardware raises an interrupt, the
>   processor uses one of several methods (to be discussed) to transfer
>   control to the ISR, whilst allowing the ISR to safely return control
>   to whatever it interrupted after execution is complete. At minimum,
>   FLAGS and CS:IP are saved and the ISR's CS:IP loaded; however, some
>   mechanisms cause a full task switch to occur before the ISR begins
>   (and another task switch when it ends).

So `IRET` isn't waste, it is minimum (and the fastest way) to return from ISR. Also all other CPU registers used in ISR must be preserved at begining and restored before `IRET` exsecution!